# \{ and \} does not work with \xdef

Tags: macros

In the MWE, when I try to use `\{ ... \}` I get the following error `! TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [input stack size=5000]`. However, if I use `\ensuremath{\lbrace} ... \ensuremath{\rbrace}` it works.

So my question is: why it works in one case and not in the other?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{xstring}

\newcommand{\AuthorA}{nameA surnameA}
\newcommand{\AuthorMailA}{surnameA@xyz.com}
\newcommand{\AuthorB}{nameB surnameB}
\newcommand{\AuthorMailB}{surnameB@xyz.com}
\newcommand{\AuthorC}{nameC surnameC}
\newcommand{\AuthorMailC}{surnameC@xyz.com}

\newcounter{Idxi}
\newcommand{\sortauthors}{%
  \setcounter{Idxi}{0}
  \foreach \Idx in \PaperAuthorsList{%
    \ifcsname Author\Idx \endcsname
      \stepcounter{Idxi}
      \expandafter\xdef\csname PaperAuthorMail\Alph{Idxi}\endcsname{\csname AuthorMail\Idx\endcsname}
    \fi
  }
  \xdef\PaperAuthorsTotalNum{\theIdxi}
}

\newcommand{\textlbrace}{\ensuremath{\lbrace}}
\newcommand{\textrbrace}{\ensuremath{\rbrace}}

\newcommand{\printauthorsmail}{%
  \def\temp{Emails:\space}%
  \foreach \Idx in {1,...,\PaperAuthorsTotalNum}{%
    \setcounter{Idxi}{\Idx}%
    %
    \ifnum\PaperAuthorsTotalNum=1%
      \xdef\temp{Email:\space\csname PaperAuthorMail\Alph{Idxi}\endcsname}%
    \fi%
    %
    \ifnum\PaperAuthorsTotalNum>1%
      \StrBefore{\csname PaperAuthorMail\Alph{Idxi}\endcsname}{@}[\PaperAuthorMailPrefix]%
      \StrBehind{\csname PaperAuthorMail\Alph{Idxi}\endcsname}{@}[\PaperAuthorMailSuffix]%
      \ifnum\Idx=1%
        \xdef\temp{\temp \{\PaperAuthorMailPrefix,\space}% <- \textlbrace instead of \{ works
      \else%
        \ifnum\Idx=\PaperAuthorsTotalNum%
          \xdef\temp{\temp \PaperAuthorMailPrefix\}@\PaperAuthorMailSuffix}% <- \textrbrace instead of \} works
        \else%
          \xdef\temp{\temp \PaperAuthorMailPrefix,\space}%
        \fi%
      \fi%
    \fi%
  }%
  \temp%
}

\begin{document}

  \newcommand\PaperAuthorsList{A}
  \sortauthors
  \printauthorsmail

  \renewcommand\PaperAuthorsList{A,B}
  \sortauthors
  \printauthorsmail

\end{document}
```

Comment: you can never use xdef (or edef) on general lists of latex tokens, only if you have full control of the input and know the exact form that the token list takes.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle in this case I know exactly what is the input.

Comment: @campa, in my case `\noexpand\{` gives the same error and `\protected@xdef`does not expand as required.

Comment: well if you have full control, don't put `\{` in there, it isn't clear what you want it to do?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, imagine the following: for a journal paper, I may have `\AuthorA ... \AuthorZ` authors and each possible author have an email `\AuthorMailA ... \AuthorMailZ`. Each `\AuthorMail...` is in the form of surname@xyz.com. So they share the same suffix (after @), but have different prefix (before @). So in order to print the emails of the authors I want something like `{...}@xyz.com`, whereas `{...}` is the prefix of author's email separated by a comma. Also, the real number of authors is less than the total number of possible authors, that is why I use `\PaperAuthorsList{...}`.

Comment: So you are using \{...\} instead of \textit{...}?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works with `\ensuremath{\lbrace}` because when TeX is doing `\xdef` it is *not* in math mode, so what you get is essentially `$\delimiter "4266308$`, which is legal in the context of an `\xdef`.

Use `\protected@xdef` instead of `\xdef`.

However, you can do better.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\Author}{mmm}
 {% #1 = key, #2 = author's name, #3 = author's email
  \prop_gput:Nnn \g_cacamailg_authors_prop
   { name #1 }{ #2 }
  \prop_gput:Nnn \g_cacamailg_authors_prop
   { email #1 } { #3 }
 }

\NewDocumentCommand{\printauthors}{m}
 {% #1 = list of keys
  \seq_clear:N \l__cacamailg_authors_temp_seq
  \clist_map_inline:nn { #1 }
   {
    \seq_put_right:Nx \l__cacamailg_authors_temp_seq
     { \prop_item:Nn \g_cacamailg_authors_prop { name ##1 } }
   }
  \seq_use:Nnnn \l__cacamailg_authors_temp_seq
   { ~and~ } % between two
   { ,~ }    % between more than two
   { ,~and~ }% between last two
 }

\NewDocumentCommand{\printemails}{m}
 {% #1 = list of keys (emails share domain)
  \int_compare:nNnTF { \clist_count:n { #1 } } = { 1 }
   { \__cacamailg_authors_email_single:n { #1 } }
   { \__cacamailg_authors_email_compress:n { #1 } }
 }

\prop_new:N \g_cacamailg_authors_prop
\tl_new:N \l__cacamailg_authors_email_domain_tl
\seq_new:N \l__cacamailg_authors_temp_seq
\seq_new:N \l__cacamailg_authors_email_names_seq

\cs_new_protected:Nn \__cacamailg_authors_email_single:n
 {
  \prop_item:Nn \g_cacamailg_authors_prop { email #1 }
 }
\cs_new_protected:Nn \__cacamailg_authors_email_compress:n
 {
  \tl_clear:N \l__cacamailg_authors_email_domain_tl
  \seq_clear:N \l__cacamailg_authors_email_names_seq
  \clist_map_function:nN { #1 } \__cacamailg_authors_email_split:n
  % print the addresses
  \{ \seq_use:Nn \l__cacamailg_authors_email_names_seq { ,~ } \}
  @\tl_use:N \l__cacamailg_authors_email_domain_tl
 }
\cs_new_protected:Nn \__cacamailg_authors_email_split:n
 {
  \__cacamailg_authors_email_split_aux:x
   { \prop_item:Nn \g_cacamailg_authors_prop { email #1 } }
 }
\cs_new_protected:Nn \__cacamailg_authors_email_split_aux:n
 {
  \__cacamailg_authors_email_split:w #1 \q_stop
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \__cacamailg_authors_email_split_aux:n { x }
\cs_new_protected:Npn \__cacamailg_authors_email_split:w #1 @ #2 \q_stop
 {
  \tl_if_empty:NT \l__cacamailg_authors_email_domain_tl
   {
    \tl_set:Nn \l__cacamailg_authors_email_domain_tl { #2 }
   }
  \seq_put_right:Nn \l__cacamailg_authors_email_names_seq { #1 }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\Author{A}{nameA surnameA}{surnameA@xyz.com}
\Author{B}{nameB surnameB}{surnameB@foo.com}
\Author{C}{nameC surnameC}{surnameC@xyz.com}

\printauthors{A,B,C}

Emails: \printemails{A,C}, \printemails{B}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Egreg, your code works fine. But in your answer you said that I shall use `\protected@xdef`, instead of `\xdef`. However, in `\xdef\temp{\temp \{ \PaperAuthorMailPrefix,\space}` and  `\xdef\temp{\temp \PaperAuthorMailPrefix \}@\PaperAuthorMailSuffix}` if I replace `\xdef` by `\protected@xdef`, the code compiles, but the result is not as expected. Is there any other workaround?

Answer (score 2):

Since the goal is to print the result, you don't need to construct a macro.  Just print it a little at a time.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{xstring}

\newcommand{\AuthorA}{nameA surnameA}
\newcommand{\AuthorMailA}{surnameA@xyz.com}
\newcommand{\AuthorB}{nameB surnameB}
\newcommand{\AuthorMailB}{surnameB@xyz.com}
\newcommand{\AuthorC}{nameC surnameC}
\newcommand{\AuthorMailC}{surnameC@xyz.com}

\newcounter{Idxi}
\newcommand{\sortauthors}{%
  \setcounter{Idxi}{0}
  \foreach \Idx in \PaperAuthorsList{%
    \ifcsname Author\Idx \endcsname
      \stepcounter{Idxi}
      \expandafter\xdef\csname PaperAuthorMail\Alph{Idxi}\endcsname{\csname AuthorMail\Idx\endcsname}
    \fi
  }
  \xdef\PaperAuthorsTotalNum{\theIdxi}
}

\newcommand{\textlbrace}{\ensuremath{\lbrace}}
\newcommand{\textrbrace}{\ensuremath{\rbrace}}

\newcommand{\printauthorsmail}{%
  Emails:\space%
  \foreach \Idx in {1,...,\PaperAuthorsTotalNum}{%
    \setcounter{Idxi}{\Idx}%
    %
    \ifnum\PaperAuthorsTotalNum=1%
      \textit{\csname PaperAuthorMail\Alph{Idxi}\endcsname}%
    \else
      \StrBefore{\csname PaperAuthorMail\Alph{Idxi}\endcsname}{@}[\PaperAuthorMailPrefix]%
      \StrBehind{\csname PaperAuthorMail\Alph{Idxi}\endcsname}{@}[\PaperAuthorMailSuffix]%
      \ifnum\Idx=\PaperAuthorsTotalNum%
        \textit{\PaperAuthorMailPrefix@\PaperAuthorMailSuffix}% <- \textrbrace instead of \} works
      \else%
        \textit{\PaperAuthorMailPrefix,\space}%
      \fi%
    \fi%
  }
}

\begin{document}

  \newcommand\PaperAuthorsList{A}
  \sortauthors
  \printauthorsmail

  \renewcommand\PaperAuthorsList{A,B}
  \sortauthors
  \printauthorsmail

\end{document}
```